# $form_state->setValue() doesn't save value

Tags: 8, forms

I have an validate code:

```
public function validateForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    parent::validateForm($form, $form_state);

    $form_state->setValue('my_variable', $form_state->getValue('my_variable') + 1);
    $form_state->setRebuild();
}
```

And I previously set `my_variable` to `1` if it's `NULL`:

```
public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

    if($form_state->getValue('my_variable') == NULL){
        $form_state->setValue('my_variable', 1);
    }
...
```

I use ajax callback for form submission and the validation works fine. After click on submit button I display `my_variable` and I see `2` (before submission it's `1`).

But when I hit the submit button again I see `2` again, instead of `3`.
Also, when I re-load the page the data is missing (so it's get value `1` again).

How to prevail the value? It looks like I am operating on copy of `$form_state` instead of reference but I cannot write **&$form_state** (`public function validateForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface &$form_state)`) because it gives me an error (as it's not the correct declaration of validateForm method).

Comment: $form_state->set('my_variable', 1); Try this

Comment: It works the same way as I described. It set variable to `1` when called in `validateForm` but that change is lost after reload of page as well as hiting sumbit button again.

Of course if I set it to `1` in both `validateForm` and `buildForm` it's always `1` (but still, the set in `validateForm` is lost after refresh/submit again).

Answer (score -3, accepted):

The value in the `$form_state` (actually everything) is lost after the PHP process ends. So there is no way to preserve your `my_variable` value via the `$form_state`. Your best option is to store this value in the session I guess.

**Example:**

```
  public function validateForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    parent::validateForm($form, $form_state);

    $session = \Drupal::request()->getSession();
    $session->set('my_variable', $session->get('my_variable') + 1);
  }

  public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $session = \Drupal::request()->getSession();

    if (empty($session->get('my_variable'))) {
      $session->set('my_variable', 1);
    }
  }
```

Do note that the data gets lost as soon as the user clears his cookies and/or the sessions gets invalidated. If you need a permanent global storage (for all users) use the [State API](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21core.api.php/group/state_api/8.3.x). For a permanent storage per user use the [Database API](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Database%21database.api.php/group/database/8.3.x).

Comment: The $form_state *does* persist between PHP processes, as this AJAX example shows: https://api.drupal.org/api/examples/form_api_example%21src%21Form%21AjaxAddMore.php/class/AjaxAddMore/8.x-1.x

Comment: Oh! please don't use State variables for handling data in forms. It's better to keep using the form state storage since Drupal will handle the data for you and will destroy it once finished. If you use Session in this context it will work but it is not whats meant to be used for. You already have a form state storage why not you just use it. Always refer to Drupal examples module: https://git.drupalcode.org/project/examples/-/blob/2d91599b3324f4636b1c79c48b4191d369bc7246/modules/form_api_example/src/Form/MultistepForm.php look for page_num variable and how you can handle it's value

Answer (score 10):

If it is a custom variable, you should use `$form_state->set('property_name', 'value')` (instead of "`$form_state->setValue(...)`").

### Example:

```php
public function validateForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    parent::validateForm($form, $form_state);

    // Update custom variable (in PHP "null + 1" equals one).
    $form_state->set('my_variable', $form_state->get('my_variable') + 1);

    // Below is only required when your "buildForm(...)" depends on the variable.
    $form_state->setRebuild();
}
```

Comment: This is the best answer and should be accepted.

Comment: In Drupal 10, you should use `$form_state->setValue('my_variable', $form_state->get('my_variable') + 1);`

Comment: **Use `->set(...)` to avoid confusion,** even if newer `->setValue(...)` sets custom-variable if it can not find any element for given `key`.

Answer (score 2):

Just to add if you'd like to actually save a form value. I do the following when using webform, I imagine it's easily modified for a usual form.

`$form['elements']['form_element']['#default_value'] = 'my_value'`

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
$form_state->setValue('VALUE_NAME', VALUE_PASSING);
```

Like -

```
public function validateForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    parent::validateForm($form, $form_state);
    $form_state->setValue('csvupload', $file->destination);
    $form_state->setValue('fid', $file->fid);
    $form_state->setRebuild();
}
```

Comment: I don't know about this... See @Top-Master's answer